# How do I measure the difference between two values within each row of my dataframe if they are separated by amino acids?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a large dataframe which features mutations in the format: "R68S, M90V, Y227A, F327A", etc. where the letters represent single letter abbreviations for amino acids, and the numbers represent the location of these mutations within the genome.

Minimal, reproducible example:

```
import pandas as pd 
data = [[31581, "wild-type"], [31614, "D250C,E296C"], [31731, "T112K,T116I,E324I,S150C,N157C,V189C,D332C"]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['SAMPLE', 'MUTATION'])
df
```

My code is as follows:

```
df2 = df1[df1["MUTATION"].str.contains("wild-type") == False]
df2["MUTATION"] = df2["MUTATION"].str.strip('(Based on UniProt and PDB), (Based on PDB), (Based on UniProt), (Based on Paper)')
filtered = df2["MUTATION"].str.split('/|;|,| |:')
filtered = df2["MUTATION"].str.split('(\d+)')

for m_item in filtered:
  if len(m_item)>=9:
    print (m_item)
```

This is how I cleaned up the data, and the new format to separate the numbers from the letters yields: "['R', '68', 'S M', '90', 'V Y', '227', 'A F', '327', 'A].  **I want to know how far apart these mutations are by producing a list of their distances, so for the above example I will need (327 - 227), (227 - 90), and (90 - 68).**  There are over 30,000 rows like this in my dataframe, so I cannot use a shortcut method.  I am new to Python, and any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). IIUC, your df column looks like this: `data = {'MUTATION': ['R68S', 'M90V', 'Y227A', 'F327A']}`, `df = pd.DataFrame(data)`. And from there you want to extract the digits (68, 90, etc.) and take the difference over the rows (NaN, 22, etc.). Correct?

Comment: @ouroboros1 Yes, that is correct!  There are also variable numbers of mutations per row, so some rows will require only 2 differences be taken, while others will require 6 or more.

Comment: Not sure if I understand what you mean there. Given `data` as just posted, you want: `[nan, 22.0, 137.0, 100.0]`, no? What are examples of rows that are to be handled differently?

Comment: Yes!  For the column "MUTATION", row 107 contains "N142P, I144P", while row 152 contains "T112K, T116I, E324I, S150C, N157C, V189C, D332C", which is what I meant by variable numbers of mutations.  I am trying to add a reproducible example to the original post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us first find all the locations of mutation from each genome then `map` a lambda function which calculates the distance between consecutive locations

```
s = df['MUTATION'].str.findall(r'\b[A-Z](\d+)[A-Z]\b')
df["DISTANCE"] = s.map(lambda l: [int(a) - int(b) for a, b in zip(l[1:], l[:-1])])
```

---

```
   SAMPLE                                   MUTATION                    DISTANCE
0   31581                                  wild-type                          []
1   31614                                D250C,E296C                        [46]
2   31731  T112K,T116I,E324I,S150C,N157C,V189C,D332C  [4, 208, -174, 7, 32, 143]
```

Comment: Was just getting to this exact answer, except that the first line of code could just be: `df['MUTATION'].str.findall(r'(\d+)')`.

Comment: Would be better to vectorise it, this is going to be brutally slow at scale

Comment: @JoshFriedlander for loops are not always bad..especially in this case :-)

Comment: Thank you both so much for your help!!

Comment: @ouroboros1 Sorry for jumping in to answer the question :-) I just wanted to make sure that the regex pattern is strict enough to not capture any unwanted noise but if the data is cleaned then I guess `\d+` would also suffice